# How to get files from FTP -server with EnsLib.FTP.PassthroughService

Tags: intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

I'm working basically with a simple task, read files from the ftp-server and write those to the file path or UNC-path. I made service (EnsLib.FTP.PassthroughService) and operation (EnsLib.File.PassthroughOperation). Service connects to the ftp server and reads directory listing, but it is not retrieving files at all. Do you have any ideas whats wrong with this or how to use EnsLib.FTP.PassthroughService?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the code snippets have tried so far to increase the clarity of your question.

Answer (score 0):

In first I would recommend to use some other tools to check if everything works is OK. Something like FileZilla for example. It is possible in some ways, like you really don't have permission to this folder and can't read what it contains. Another reason you have some errors in configuration, and may be you an errors in  Ensemble's error log, and I think you should check it too.

Comment: I did check with FileZilla that everything works and account has sufficient permissions.

But anyway I solved the problem. I had to select MSDOS as Server List Style from the settings. Default value was Unix.